# Error on starting application Bundler::GemNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, rack, rack-pow

I have just started a new app but am getting this error when I click the 'about your application's environment' link on the Welcome aboard page.

> Error starting application Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow
>   tried to run it.
>
> Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find activesupport-3.2.6 in any of the
>   sources

My app is running:

- Rails 3.2.6
- Ruby 1.9.3p194
- Rubygems 1.8.24
- RVM 1.14.5
- POW 0.4.0

I found similar questions where the problem was to do wit husing passenger, but I'm not using that.

When I run gem list I get:

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> actionmailer (3.2.6) actionpack (3.2.6) activemodel (3.2.6)
>   activerecord (3.2.6) activeresource (3.2.6) activesupport (3.2.6) arel
>   (3.0.2) builder (3.0.0) bundler (1.1.4) coffee-rails (3.2.2)
>   coffee-script (2.2.0) coffee-script-source (1.3.3) daemon_controller
>   (1.0.0) erubis (2.7.0) execjs (1.4.0) fastthread (1.0.7) hike (1.2.1)
>   i18n (0.6.0) journey (1.0.4) jquery-rails (2.0.2) json (1.7.3) mail
>   (2.4.4) mime-types (1.19) multi_json (1.3.6) passenger (3.0.13)
>   polyglot (0.3.3) rack (1.4.1) rack-cache (1.2) rack-ssl (1.3.2)
>   rack-test (0.6.1) rails (3.2.6) railties (3.2.6) rake (0.9.2.2) rdoc
>   (3.12) rubygems-bundler (1.0.3) rvm (1.11.3.4) sass (3.1.20)
>   sass-rails (3.2.5) sprockets (2.4.3, 2.1.3) sqlite3 (1.3.6) thor
>   (0.15.4, 0.15.3) tilt (1.3.3) treetop (1.4.10) tzinfo (0.3.33)
>   uglifier (1.2.6)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

**update**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

**gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.6)
      actionpack (= 3.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.6)
      activemodel (= 3.2.6)
      activesupport (= 3.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.3)
    activemodel (3.2.6)
      activesupport (= 3.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.6)
      activemodel (= 3.2.6)
      activesupport (= 3.2.6)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.6)
      activemodel (= 3.2.6)
      activesupport (= 3.2.6)
    activesupport (3.2.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.3)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.6)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.6)
      actionpack (= 3.2.6)
      activerecord (= 3.2.6)
      activeresource (= 3.2.6)
      activesupport (= 3.2.6)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.6)
    railties (3.2.6)
      actionpack (= 3.2.6)
      activesupport (= 3.2.6)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.20)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.6)
    thor (0.15.4)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.6)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 3.2.6)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

I have run bundle install which completed fine. However, if I run sudo bundle install I get:

```
/Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7):

Pow is probably trying to start your app with the "bundle exec" prefix. That means that your app will only see the gem which are in the Gemfile (and more precisely, only the gems which are in the groups of your current environment).

This is great because it enables you to have multiple apps using the same gem in different version : You might have an app using Rails 2 and another one using Rails 3, both are installed on your system but your first app says it depend on Rails 2 in its Gemfile and the other one specify Rails 3 as a dependency.

Long story short : You must declare each of your dependency in the Gemfile and run "bundle install" before accessing your app.

One more advice : Don't forget to specify the version of rake and even bundler you use, that might save your life when you upgrade those gems on your dev system but not on your prod server

Comment: Thanks for the response, How do you mean declare the dependencies? I've added my gemfile to my question. Is it declared as gem 'rails', '3.2.6'?

Comment: Your Gemfile seems ok, have you run bundle install ? Can you post your Gemfile.lock ?

Comment: I've added the lock file now.

Comment: Everything looks fine, you shouldn't "sudo" when you type "bundle install" because you use rvm which is install in your user's home not root's home.
Can you tell me what happens when you type "bundle exec rails s" and go to localhost:3000 ?

Comment: It look like pow and rvm do not play well together in latest versions 

Maybe you can find help here : https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/271 and try the magic command : "rvm env -- [ruby]@[gemset] > .powenv"

You might also want to try rben which seems much easier to integrate with pow

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error: Solved by below commands:

```
rvm use ruby-version

gem install rails
```